# Find the sum, count, maximum and minimum number of an array with negative values

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
int findHighest(int row, int col, int high, int a[row][col]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        high = INT_MIN;
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            if (a[x][y] > high) {
                high = a[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
    return high;
}

int findLowest(int row, int col, int low, int a[row][col]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        low = INT_MAX;
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            if (a[x][y] < low) {
                low = a[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
    return low;
}
```

this is the code I wrote to print the sum, count, highest and lowest number of each rows in an array. But I ended up with a printed results in the last rows of array.

Comment: Please share the code in the text format, not a picture

Comment: These two functions will only send the highest and lowest value in the last row of the array. If you need a row specific highest and lowest value, you need an array as output (each entry for each row) instead of single value

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int findSum(int row, int col, int sum, int a[row][col]) ;
int findHighest(int row, int col, int high, int a[row][col]) ;
int findLowest(int row, int col, int low, int a[row][col]) ;

int main() {
    int row, col;
    
    printf("Enter number of groups: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("Enter number of values per group: ");
    scanf("%d", &col);
    int a[row][col];
    printf("\n");

    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            printf("Enter value in a[%d][%d]: ", x, y);
            scanf("%d", &a[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Elements in the array: \n");
    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            printf("Element in a[%d][%d]: %d\n", x, y, a[x][y]);
        }
    }
    
    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        
        int sum = 0, high = INT_MIN, low = INT_MAX;
        
        printf("\nRow: %d\n",x+1);
        
        sum = findSum(x, col, sum, a);
        high = findHighest(x, col, high, a);
        low = findLowest(x, col, low, a);
    
        printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
        printf("Count: %d\n", col);
        printf("Highest: %d\n", high);
        printf("Lowest: %d\n", low);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since you didn't provide the definitions of the functions findSum, findHighest, findLowest, I would write my own considering you want the result for every row. So the definitions would be:

```
int findSum(int row, int col, int sum, int a[row][col]) {
    sum = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
        sum += a[row][y];
    }
    return sum;
}

int findHighest(int row, int col, int high, int a[row][col]) {
    high = INT_MIN;
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
        if (a[row][y] > high) {
            high = a[row][y];
        }
    }
    return high;
}

int findLowest(int row, int col, int low, int a[row][col]) {
    low = INT_MAX;
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
        if (a[row][y] < low) {
            low = a[row][y];
        }
    }
    return low;
}
```

Hence, the final working code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int findSum(int row, int col, int sum, int a[row][col]) ;
int findHighest(int row, int col, int high, int a[row][col]) ;
int findLowest(int row, int col, int low, int a[row][col]) ;

int main() {
    int row, col;

    printf("Enter number of groups: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("Enter number of values per group: ");
    scanf("%d", &col);
    int a[row][col];
    printf("\n");

    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            printf("Enter value in a[%d][%d]: ", x, y);
            scanf("%d", &a[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Elements in the array: \n");
    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            printf("Element in a[%d][%d]: %d\n", x, y, a[x][y]);
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {

        int sum = 0, high = INT_MIN, low = INT_MAX;

        printf("\nRow: %d\n",x+1);

        sum = findSum(x, col, sum, a);
        high = findHighest(x, col, high, a);
        low = findLowest(x, col, low, a);

        printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
        printf("Count: %d\n", col);
        printf("Highest: %d\n", high);
        printf("Lowest: %d\n", low);
    }

    return 0;
}


int findSum(int row, int col, int sum, int a[row][col]) {
    sum = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
        sum += a[row][y];
    }
    return sum;
}

int findHighest(int row, int col, int high, int a[row][col]) {
    high = INT_MIN;
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
        if (a[row][y] > high) {
            high = a[row][y];
        }
    }
    return high;
}

int findLowest(int row, int col, int low, int a[row][col]) {
    low = INT_MAX;
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
        if (a[row][y] < low) {
            low = a[row][y];
        }
    }
    return low;
}
```

You can just click this link to see the code in an online compiler and execute it to verify the results: https://onlinegdb.com/ImB8p9DpL

In order to get the results for every row, you need to pass the row number for which you want the results in the function, not the total number of rows. That's why you were getting results only for last row. Also the functions findSum, findHighest, findLowest need to be defined in such a way that they work on a particular row, not the whole matrix as I see in your recent edit.